# expressでfontをimportできない

Tags: javascript, font

Nuxt.js + Expressで開発を行っており、PDFkitで領収書を作るためにfontにmeiryoを入れようとしております

```
import PDFDocument from 'pdfkit'
router.post('/pdf', (req, res) => {
     const doc = new PDFDocument({ size: 'A4', margin: 50 })
     doc.font('static/fonts/meiryo.ttf') //ここで止まる
```

上記の様な内容で、formからpostを行ったところ、doc.fontにたどり着いた瞬間にサーバエラー（ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE）になってしまいます。
エラーログも出ておらず、何が悪いのかわからず困っています。

Comment: 変数の`doc`が何を指しているのか読み取れないので、全体がわかるようにコードを載せると回答しやすいと思います。

Comment: すいません、Docの宣言が抜けていたため修正しました。

Comment: おそらく、expressのエラーではなく、pdfkitのエラーが発生したことが原因でサーバーのエラーが出ていると考えられるんで、pdfkitだけを利用したコードで実行したエラーログを掲示することは可能ですか？

Comment: すいません、fontのパスを絶対パスで入力したら解決しました。失礼しました。